# Getting a RCP feature to export to a p2 site that supports multiple platforms using Buckminster

Tags: eclipse, build, rcp, pde, buckminster

I have a simple RCP Plugin (with a product) and I want it to run in atleast Linux and Windows (32 and 64bit). I have a product that contains a Feature from which buckminster uses to create the p2.site. (I only use a build.properties and buckminster.properties files, no *.cspec and *.rmap files, since these probably get generated by buckminster from the RCP product/feature files).

My problem is that my feature has a link to the 64bit linux swt plugin (I'm running 64bit linux) but if I add references to the windows swt plugins to my RCP .product the buckminster build fails to resolve these plugins and then does not export the p2.site correctly.

How do I get buckminster to build the p2 site by looking at the dependencies of my RCP .product file and if it doesn't resolve the win32 or win64 swt libraries from my workspace that it will look else where for these dependencies?

I like the idea of buckminster determining my project dependencies from my .product file so I don't have to keep a .cspec and a .product file in sync, when I make changes to my project's dependencies. If the dependencies are not found on my workspace then I want buckminster to find the missing dependencies (could be all of them if running from Hudson server) from "maybe" a .rmap etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute your site.p2 target several times, to provide a build for each platform.

See the tutorial on [the Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Building_an_RCP_application_with_hudson_%28Buckminster%29) or on [Ralf Ebert's blog](http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/rcp_builds/) about more specific details.

Comment: The problem I have is that my feature.xml refers to all platforms (eg: swt_win32 swt_linux32 swt_win64 swt_linux32 etc) in its dependency list and this list is used by buckminster to generate the site, but when it can't resolve one of the dependancies (i.e like when it runs from my linux box) the site isn't generated correctly (because it fails)

Comment: My problem is that I can't even get it to run the first time successfully if my feature.xml refers to a dependancy that buckminster can;t resolve.... now I don't want to set up all "target platforms" for every developer's IDE workspace just build the project to a site.p2...

Comment: Couldn't you make these platform-dependent requirements optional to allow explicitely loading them one by one as described in the tutorials?

Comment: I removed the platform-dependent requirements from the feature.xml and it seems to work.